# A expressão "olha vê" é correta do ponto de vista gramatical?

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática, expressões, português-europeu, sintaxe

Quando vou na rua ouço muito a expressão "olha vê!".

Exemplo de uso:

> — Olha vê o Sol!
>   Olha vê o Paulo! Olha vê a praia como está bonita

Do ponto de vista gramatical, considerando a norma culta, é correto utilizar esta expressão?

Comment: Exemplo" Olha vê o sol"

Comment: É utilizado de uma forma mais informal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considerando a norma culta da Língua Portuguesa, não seria correto o uso da expressão. É evidente a presença do pleonasmo, uma figura de linguagem em que uma ideia é reiterada por outras palavras ou expressões de maneira óbvia. Um exemplo dessa figura é a expressão "descer para baixo", uma vez que descer só pode significar ir para baixo. Contudo, por ser uma figura de linguagem, o pleonasmo pode ser tranquilamente aplicado no gênero lírico.